# How do I add buttons, switches etc. to an android app drawer?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, android-actionbar

How do I add buttons, switches, seekbars etc. to an android app drawer? 
I know how to add text to the listview but I'm finding the above very difficult. I have my current app drawer below. What changes would you suggest to accomplish the above.

Code:

**MainActivity**

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        // Within which the entire activity is enclosed
        DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

        // ListView represents Navigation Drawer
        ListView mDrawerList;

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle indicates the presence of Navigation Drawer in the action bar
        ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

        // Title of the action bar
        String mTitle="";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mTitle = (String) getTitle();

            // Getting reference to the DrawerLayout
            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

            mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

            // Getting reference to the ActionBarDrawerToggle
            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle( this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close){

                    /** Called when drawer is closed */
                    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                        invalidateOptionsMenu();
                    }

                    /** Called when a drawer is opened */
                    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                        getActionBar().setTitle("Select a river");
                        invalidateOptionsMenu();
                    }
            };

            // Setting DrawerToggle on DrawerLayout
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

            // Creating an ArrayAdapter to add items to the listview mDrawerList
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getBaseContext(),
                R.layout.drawer_list_item ,
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rivers)
            );

            // Setting the adapter on mDrawerList
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Enabling Home button
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

            // Enabling Up navigation
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            // Setting item click listener for the listview mDrawerList
            mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                    View view,
                    int position,
                    long id) {

                        // Getting an array of rivers
                        String[] rivers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rivers);

                        //Currently selected river
                        mTitle = rivers[position];

                        // Creating a fragment object
                        RiverFragment rFragment = new RiverFragment();

                        // Creating a Bundle object
                        Bundle data = new Bundle();

                        // Setting the index of the currently selected item of mDrawerList
                        data.putInt("position", position);

                        // Setting the position to the fragment
                        rFragment.setArguments(data);

                        // Getting reference to the FragmentManager
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

                        // Creating a fragment transaction
                        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                        // Adding a fragment to the fragment transaction
                        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, rFragment);

                        // Committing the transaction
                        ft.commit();

                        // Closing the drawer
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }

        /** Handling the touch event of app icon */
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        /** Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // If the drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
            boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);

            menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
            return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**Activity_Layout**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library for your drawer [library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

or if you want this drawer then put one linearlayout and then put you views inside that.

```
 SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
 menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
 menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
 menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
 menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
 menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
 menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
 menu.setMenu(R.layout.side_panel);
```

Now in the side panel layout put your views in side that now for view side panel use this:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        if (menu != null) {
            menu.toggle();
        } 
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

for initializing side panel data use this:

```
menu.findViewById(R.id.your_view_id).setOnClickListener(this);
```

and override onclick event and handle that you want.

for further information see the example in the github.

Comment: Although that sounds easy enough, could you please show an example. So I can get my head around it?

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something, but I really don't understand the above.. How does this enable me to add buttons, switches, etc. to an android app drawer?

Comment: menu.setMenu(R.layout.side_panel); in this layout put your buttons,switches etc. and all the things.

Comment: if you still dont't understand this then download the code from github and run the example that is given in the zip.

Comment: I have not used the library slidingMenu, I can't figure out whether this fits into the above program. Similarly the method onMenuItemSelected isn't part of the above. How does this link with my code expressed above?

Comment: just add that library in your project.

Comment: Isn't there another way? I thought by the way you answered the question, that you knew of another method which didn't require the inclusion of a further library.